# CSS - Colour fill to the left of a container

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to color fill to the left of a div (outside a container) -

[image]

It needs to go from the right of the left side of the container to the edge of the window width (even on resize). Does anyone have any idea how i can achieve this? My initial thought was repeating a `5px` width image to the left of the same color but not sure if this is able to be done. Thanks in advance.

my logo is sitting up the top left with this css

```
.serviceof {    
    width: auto;
    float: left;
    background-color: #012051;
    padding: 15px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

and my html

```
<div class="logobg" style="background-image:url(themes/startertoplight/img/logobg.png)"></div>
<div class="serviceof">
 <img src="themes/startertoplight/img/service.png" height="114px">
</div>
```

Comment: [please include the markup you've tried and a description of what you've had trouble with](http://whathaveyoutried.com). Asking for someone else to write code for you isn't going to be helpful to anyone in the future.

Comment: please add the html code

Comment: Have you tried just adding a left border?

Comment: @DavidP yes i did try that but it pushes the logo to the right rather than keeping it fixed and adding the border to the left

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a couple of pseudo-elements.

No extra HTML and it automatically resizes to the container width and banner height.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-top: none;
  height: 250px;
}
.banner {
  height: 75px;
  background: green;
  position: relative;
}
.banner::before,
.banner::after {
  content: '';
  width: 50vw;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
.banner::before {
  background: rebeccapurple;
  right: 100%;
}
.banner::after {
  left: 100%;
  background: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="banner"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: awesome this worked perfect! thanks very much

Answer (score 1):

You could use CSS3 gradient over only 1 pixel to get a hard line. You might be able to adjust the following to your needs.

```
.banner{
    background: #009dff;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  #009dff 150px, #006e2e 151px, #006e2e 151px);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  #009dff 150px,#006e2e 151px,#006e2e 151px);
    background: linear-gradient(to right,  #009dff 150px,#006e2e 151px,#006e2e 151px);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#009dff', endColorstr='#006e2e',GradientType=1 );
    width: 100%;
}
```

See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dval/jj5uyvy3/) for example.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
.bar{
    width: 100%;
    height: 114px;
}
.container{
    width:960px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
.serviceof{
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #012051;
    height: 114px;
    width: 15px;
}
    .logobg{
    background-image:url(themes/startertoplight/img/logobg.png);
    position: relative;
    left:0;
    top:0;
}



<div class="bar">
    <div class="serviceof">
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="logobg">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```